# Check if CredSSP is enabled with Powershell remotely

Tags: powershell-3.0, credssp

I'm having trouble trying to check a list of remote machines if CredSSP is enabled.  When my script connects to the machine and executes the command.  It ends up returning false.  If I connect to that same machine via RDP and execute the same command, it will return true.  Here is my script:

```
foreach ($server in $servers.Split(",").Trim()) {
   $pw = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
   $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentList "Domain\user", $pw
   $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred

   $output = (Get-Item  WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\CredSSP).value

   Write-Host $server : $output

   Remove-PSSession -Session $session
}
```

Does anyone have an insight into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not running `Get-Item` remotely.

Try:

```
$ServerList = $servers.Split(",").Trim();
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force;
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentList "Domain\user", $pw;

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerList -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { Get-Item  WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\CredSSP; } |
    Select-Object PSComputerName, Value;
```

You could use `Invoke-Command -Session $session` instead `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerList`, but there's no need to make a loop and mess around creating and removing sessions by hand.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was helpful.  I'm still fairly new to PS.  So, correct me if I'm wrong, but by wrapping Get-Item with those session calls was essentially doing nothing?  It was just executing locally?  Is there a way to accomplish the same thing with a session?  I might expand upon this script and it becomes much larger.

Comment: @Anthony Yes, that's it exactly.  It was executing locally.  You can use sessions with Invoke-Command, but that's typically for more complex situations where you need to run several different script blocks or otherwise need to maintain session state remotely.  I don't think I've written anything that's required it in a long time.  It does work, however.